# No main manifest attribute after creating jar, Cmd Windows

Tags: java, jar, cmd, compilation, program-entry-point

I want to create a jar from command line in Windows with this script:

```
cd Mongo-SQL/src
javac -cp "..\\lib\\*;..\\lib\\hapi-lib\\*" *.java FHIRTranslate\*.java
jar -cvfm ..\\lib\\runSQLSave.jar ..\\META-INF\\MANIFEST.MF *.class
```

And the Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: ..\\lib\\*.jar ..\\lib\\hapi-lib\\*.jar
Main-Class: Main
```

After I run the script I didn't receive any error, but when I want to run the runSQLSave.jar I receive

> no main manifest attribute, in runSQLSave.jar

In my Manifest file I don't have `Main-Class: Main`. Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The Class-path entries in the manifest are relative URLs, not Windows paths. They should use forward slashes. It does not support wildcards AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify entry point class using -e flag See this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)